# Подскажите . это в git hub как изменить шрифт

Tags: github

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите . это в git hub     как изменить шрифт

Comment: Может проблема в кодировке символов, а не в шрифте? Если да, так перекодировка всех файлов проекта в *UTF-8* должна помочь.

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: да наверно в UTF-8  попробую  спасибо

Comment: каким то образом все заработало